# How can I prevent my cart form being empty after checkout payment failure magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout

magentno 2 I want user to keep its shopping cart after payment failure. Cart becomes empty when cancel the payment transaction in checkout.

How should I change the Failure.php in Magento checkout module?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

In `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement` at line 550 the quote is being made inactive.  So I commented out the following code:

```
// $quote->setIsActive(false);
// $this->eventManager->dispatch(
//     'sales_model_service_quote_submit_success',
//     [
//         'order' => $order,
//         'quote' => $quote
//     ]
// );
// $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

This would also help you to maintain cart state if the user goes back from the payment page back to checkout page.

Comment: How will this affect the stock quantity of the products in the cart.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions for **Magento 2.3.5**. Please override **Failure.php**(Core file path: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage) and change *public function* as below

```
public function execute()
{
   
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
    
    $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
        $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        //$this->messageManager->addWarningMessage('Payment Failed.');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's creating a quote id with null reserved order id and also redirecting to checkout cart page but item is removing from cart.

Answer (score 1):

For magento 2 please try and inject `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession` to `_construct` and write...

```
$this->checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
```

...in your `Failure.php`

Answer (score 0):

This depends by the payment method you use... as some of them offer the feature you want. Take a look at **Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::restoreQuote()** to get an idea about what to do

```
/**
 * Restore last active quote
 *
 * @return bool True if quote restored successfully, false otherwise
 */
public function restoreQuote()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $this->getLastRealOrder();
    if ($order->getId()) {
        try {
            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
            $this->replaceQuote($quote)->unsLastRealOrderId();
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch('restore_quote', ['order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote]);
            return true;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ok thx for reply ill check this Mr.Raul

Comment: This is not a copy/paste answer... sorry. It's just an orientation about what your payment method should do, in the case it fails

Comment: oh ok ok thx any exact idea pls

Comment: Cannot be exact if we can't know what payment method we are talking about ;)

Comment: its PayUIndia_Payu payment method

Comment: That's not a default payment method, so we can't see the code... you'd contact developers or do the work yourself

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solutions for **Magento 2.3.5**. Please override **Failure.php**(Core file path: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage) and change *public function* as below

```
public function execute()
{
    
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
    
    $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
        $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        //$this->messageManager->addWarningMessage('Payment Failed.');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```